How can I serialize VersionedTransaction in Solana with python?
I built sending several txs in one jito bundle with Node.js.
I want convert this code to python.
When I use jito bundle, I should serialize transactions.
When I use Node.js, I can use transaction.serialize().
But when I use python, I used transaction.serialize(), it occurs error.

'solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction' object has no attribute 'serialize'

How can I serialize VersionedTransaction in Solana with python?

It looks like VersionedTransaction implements bytes at https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/c10419c29b7890e69572f0160e5e74406814048b/python/solders/transaction.pyi#L121, so you should be able to serialize the transaction with:
bytes(transaction)

This is how you send transactions with solders/solanapy
I believe the serialization is built in here somehwere. You don't have to do it manually.
msg= MessageV0.try_compile(
    payer=owner.pubkey(),
    instructions=[burn_ix],
    address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
    recent_blockhash=latest_blockhash,
)

tx = VersionedTransaction(msg, [owner])

response = rpc.send_transaction(tx)

